# Resolution and accuracy of a stereo camera

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

My question is pertaining to how the parameters of a stereo camera system (focal length, base, height, pixel density) affects the accuracy as well as the resolution of depth measurement.  I do not have a formal background in computer vision or photogrammetry, I have a civil engineering background.

From what I understand, accuracy determines the error in measurement of depth. Say, the depth of a point is 2.1 meter and it is estimated by the stereo camera as 2.2 meter, then the error is 0.1 m.

Resolution is similar to least count, it is the least detectable change in measurement that can be done by the stereo camera system. Example, if the resolution is 1 meter, then it can differentiate between two points that are at depths of 5 meter and 7 meter (because depth difference is greater than the resolution i.e. 2 m > 1 m). BUT it cannot differentiate between two points which have depths 5 meter and 5.5 meter (because depth difference is less than the resolution i.e. 0.5 m < 1 m).

In Chapter 2, section 2.4 of [this PhD thesis](https://scholarbank.nus.edu.sg/handle/10635/118287) (Parameter and quantization analysis), what does the author mean by the term del Z , is it the error or the least count in depth measurement ?

In this [first paper](http://media.tkk.fi/visualmedia/reports/EI-papers-2011/Kyto_MethodForMeasuringStereoCameraDepthAccuracy.pdf) they have defined del Z as the resolution and in this [second paper](https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Quantization%20Error%20Analysis%20in%20Stereo%20Vision&btnG=) they have defined it as error. Can you guide me through my confusion?

PhD thesis : Depth recovery and parameter analysis using single-lens prism based stereovision system by KEE WEI LOON

First paper : Method for measuring stereo camera depth accuracy based on stereoscopic vision by Mikko Kytö*, Mikko Nuutinen, Pirkko Oittinen

Second paper : Quantization error analysis in stereo vision by C Chang, S Chatterjee

Also, can you point me to a source (for example a textbook) which deals with how resolution of a stereo camera can be found from it's parameters ?